# Android - what is this widget? (A sort of context menu)

Tags: android, android-widget, contextmenu

I've searched and searched and for some reason cannot find how to create one of these.

Are they custom?  I used to see them in some fairly basic looking apps and assumed they would be part of the API:

[image: Google Docs]
[image: Whatsapp]

Answer (score 0):

[There](http://materializecss.com/buttons.html) is something like this, i love materialize+bootstrap <3